# Strapi hit (post view) counter

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I want to implement post view (number of visited) functionality but can not figure it out how to do that.
My idea, create a new field "view counter" and in the frontend increment the number and update the field, but then I have to allow global update which can be risky, anyone with some knowledge can update the whole post. or I am missing something?

any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you don't manage that in Strapi but using a tool like Google Analytics in your frontend application.

This kind of tool will be able to give you this type of information.

After that, if you want to manage that in the Strapi side.
You can use the life cycle of your Article/Post model.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/models.html#life-cycle-callbacks

And use the after fetch to increment the `count` value.
With that, that is your backend that manages this logic.

Comment: Thanks. For stable docs, https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/models.html#life-cycle-callbacks